# for loop to create data frames which are subsets of another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, subset

I'm trying to create a for loop that creates subsets of my original data

Right now I create subsets as follows:

```
Dataset_1 <- subset(Dataset1, compliance>=0)    
Dataset_2 <- subset(Dataset1, compliance>=5) 
Dataset_3 <- subset(Dataset1, compliance>=10)
Dataset_4 <- subset(Dataset1, compliance>=15)
Dataset_5 <- subset(Dataset1, compliance>=20)
Dataset_6 <- subset(Dataset1, compliance>=25)
```

However, I would like to use a for loop to do this and was thinking something like this might work:

```
Dataset_ = {}
for (i in 1:6){
  Dataset_[[i]] = subset(Dataset1, compliance>=(0+(i-1)*5))
}
```

When I do this, I get a list with data frames in it. However, I was wondering whether there is a way to write the for loop so that the data frames are not put in a list but instead made as individual data frames. Reason: I would like to save the data frames that are created as .Rdata files in a folder e.g.:

```
save(Dataset_2, file = "Hypothesis1/Dataset1.RData")
save(Dataset_3, file = "Hypothesis1/Dataset2.RData")
save(Dataset_4, file = "Hypothesis1/Dataset3.RData")
```

Comment: Try `assign(paste0("Dataset_",i), subset(Dataset1, compliance>=(0+(i-1)*5)))` instead of your `Dataset_[[i]] = subset(Dataset1, compliance>=(0+(i-1)*5))`

Comment: Or just `for (i in 1:6){ save(subset(Dataset1, compliance>=(0+(i-1)*5)), file = sprintf("Hypothesis1/Dataset%s.RData", i)) }`.

Comment: Try assign(paste0("Dataset_",i), subset(Dataset1, compliance>=(0+(i-1)*5))) instead of your Dataset_[[i]] = subset(Dataset1, compliance>=(0+(i-1)*5)) 

This works, thank you very much :)

Comment: @ulfelder post as answer please.

Comment: @Jeroen post your answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a list. You can just write the files directly to disk within your `for` loop as follows:

```
for (i in seq(6)) {

  save(subset(Dataset1, compliance >= (0 + (i-1) * 5)),
       file = sprintf("Hypothesis1/Dataset%s.RData", i))

}
```